# Hive Partitions using Column Keys with High Cardinality

Tags: hive

Does hive perform well in partitioning with high degrees of cardinality? The partitioning column keys are **not** a finite set.

Example:
I partition with 2 column keys: `date_a` and `date_b`. Assume I have 365 degrees for both `date_a` and `date_b`, translating to 365 x 365 = 133,225 total partitions.

Will this blow up in memory usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, i would say it will be bad for HDFS. It will not literally blow up your HDFS but it will slow down table, create 133,225 individual files of same huge size.
I would say, choose something realistic like `month+year`. This will give you better control, even distribution. In case of date partition, weekends and holidays can have 0 data.
So please analyze what is 'the' evenly distributed count combination and then choose that one.